# submenu does not open on mobile

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML:

```
<nav class="mkdf-main-menu mkdf-drop-down mkdf-default-nav">
    <ul id="menu-home-menu" class="clearfix">
        <li id="nav-menu-item-3436" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home  narrow">
            <a href="https://website" class="">
                <span class="item_outer">
                    <span class="item_text">Home</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-3437" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-property-item  narrow">
            <a href="https://website/p" class="">
                <span class="item_outer">
                    <span class="item_text">Projekt</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-3463" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-property-item  narrow">
            <a href="https://website/pr" class="">
                <span class="item_outer">
                    <span class="item_text">Lage</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-4855" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children mkdf-active-item has_sub narrow">
            <a href="https://website/gruyu" class=" current ">
                <span class="item_outer">
                    <span class="item_text">Häuser</span>
                    <i class="mkdf-menu-arrow fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
            <div class="second">
                <div class="inner">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="nav-menu-item-3478" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
                            <a href="https://website/grundrissnavigator/" class="">
                                <span class="item_outer">
                                    <span class="item_text">Grundrissnavigator</span>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="nav-menu-item-3477" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page ">
                            <a href="https://website/preisliste/" class="">
                                <span class="item_outer">
                                    <span class="item_text">Preisliste</span>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="nav-menu-item-3476" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-3473 current_page_item ">
                            <a href="https://website/aufd" class="">
                                <span class="item_outer">
                                    <span class="item_text">Ausstattung</span>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-4686" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow">
            <a href="https://website/g" class="">
                <span class="item_outer">
                    <span class="item_text">Galerie</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-4807" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom  narrow">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://website/" class="">
                <span class="item_outer">
                    <span class="item_text">Exposé</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-3466" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page  narrow">
            <a href="https://website/k" class="">
                <span class="item_outer">
                    <span class="item_text">Kontakt</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And this submenu that is on class second in the html, wont open in mobile.

This my css

```
.second {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: -10px;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transition: top .15s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top .15s ease-out;
    transition: top .15s ease-out;
```

I tried to put every other display option but still does not work, any help?

Comment: Please indent your html code properly! Is it really necessary to keep any classnames in the html except "second", to demonstrate your point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following properties need to be changed so that the menu is visible for your scenario on mobile:

```
.second {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
    visibility: visible; 
}
```

For example, you could use the following to display the submenu when the parent menu item is hovered on. The left and top properties should be adjusted to fit your layout:

```
.menu-item-has-children:hover .second {
     left: 85px;
     opacity: 1;
     top: 70px;
     visibility: visible; 
}
```

Comment: The problem is submenu on mobile opens on click

Comment: In that case, you can add the styles from the ".menu-item-has-children:hover .second"  example to a new class name and then, using javascript, toggle this class name when the parent item is clicked. This will allow you show and hide the submenu each time the parent menu item is clicked.

Here is an example of how to toggle the class with javascript:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp